# Generalized Linear Model (GLM) in Python

Tags: regression, logistic, python, generalized-linear-model

Say that my data consists of

| time | success | failure | exog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 3 | 1002 | 0.2 |
| 2010 | 2 | 1200 | 0.3 |
| 2011 | 9 | 1091 | 0.1 |
| 2012 | 0 | 1099 | 0.4 |

And I want to fit a **GLM** with a **Binomial family** and **Logit link** to this grouped timeseries data.

E.g. The function would be "success + failure ~ exog + intercept".

When using this data to fit a model in Python using the GLM from statsmodels.api library, it seem to work. **However**, my last data point is 0 success, which means when computing the proportion success / (success + failure), it becomes 0.

How can the logit transformation be calculated when this ratio is 0? Maybe I am missing something regarding MLE...